# Widgets not activated alert after using get_sidebar()

Tags: widgets, sidebar, register-sidebar

I stumbled upon avery strange problem while creating a sidebar for my wordpress theme using the **get_sidebar()** function in **header.php**.

I inserted the following code in **function.php**:

```
function myfunc_sidebars_init() {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => __('Main Sidebar', 'mytheme'),
        'description' => __('Widget area for the main sidebar.', 'mytheme'),
        'id' => 'sidebar-main',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
        ));
    }
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'myfunc_sidebars_init' );
```

My **sideber.php** looks like this:

```
<div id="sidebar1" class="fluid-sidebar sidebar span4" role="complementary">

<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar1' ) ) : ?>

    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar1' ); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <div class="alert alert-message">

        <p><?php _e("Please activate some Widgets","mytheme"); ?>.</p>

    </div>

<?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

I also selected the sidebar in **Appearance->Menus** in the admin panel and all default widgets are added to the sidebar in **Appearance->Widgets** (Search, Recent Posts, Recent Comments, etc.).

However after loading the theme there is an alert in the sidebar menu saying *"Please activate some Widgets"*. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've changed from `sidebar-main` in your `myfunc_sidebars_init()` to `sidebar1` in `sidebar.php`.  Change `sidebar.php` to use

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-main' ) ) : ?>

    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-main' ); ?>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! That was very stupid mistake of mine..

Comment: I've chased down typos like that for *hours* before. Now I tend to look for stuff like that first.